# Installing package with git, receiving error

Tags: git, pip, python-3.7

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\utente\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-0y52n23d\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-0y52n23d\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-0y52n23d\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "c:\users\utente\anaconda3\lib\tokenize.py", line 447, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-0y52n23d\setup.py'
    ----------------------------------------

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

**What should I do?**

Comment: what does git do in here?

Comment: I run "pip install git+https://github.com/smarthi/satellite-images.git"

Comment: what is is supposed to do?

Comment: It should download and add the github profile files

Answer (score 1):

The repository https://github.com/smarthi/satellite-images lacks `setup.py`. It's not a `pip`-installable package. [Ask](https://github.com/smarthi/satellite-images/issues) the authors how it's supposed to be installed and used.